# Changing JavaScript object variable after time delay

Tags: javascript

```
this.anim= true;
```

How to change this object's variable to `false` after `x` seconds?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
this.anim = true;
var that = this; // you store the reference to a `this` in `that` variable,
                 // so you could use it in a callback function. You have
                 // to do that because it has its own `this` defined
setTimeout(function() {
    that.anim = false;
}, x * 1000);
```

or

```
this.anim = true;

(function(that){ // you create an IIFE (see http://tinyurl.com/js-iife)
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.anim = false;
    }, x * 1000);
}(this)); // and invoke it with `this` as a parameter, which will be available
          // as `that` in the function body
```

Comment: please add comments what you have done in code! so, OP can understand it! +1 from my side!

Comment: [and a reference too just for good measure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout)

Comment: @Aspiring Aqib: is it enough? The other is pretty obvious