# Assign value to a variable after a certain amount of time

Tags: javascript, python, timing, psychopy

I am really new to JavaScript, so please bear with me :)

I am trying to assign a value of `1` to a variable (`var_1`) after a certain amount of time (2500 milliseconds).

Do you think this is a good way to achieve this?

```
var var_1;
function loading(){
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        var_1 = 1; 
    }, 2500);
}
```

I am basing myself on a Python script for Psychopy, and I am trying to translate it. This was my code:

```
#Begin Routine
timer = core.Clock()
max_time = 2.5

#Each Frame
if timer.getTime()>max_time:
    var_1 = 1
```

Comment: Please don't tag javascript questions with the Java tag. The languages are as different as Austria and Australia.

Comment: What is a good way? This, in my opinion, is atleast not bad.

Comment: Seems good since it follows this previous answer on [changing JavaScript variable after time delay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899564/changing-javascript-object-variable-after-time-delay).  Note: in your code, you only declared a function to change the variable, but you need to run loading to actually change the variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Javascript, you would have to call the `loading` function for the timeout to actually happen.

But you can always not use the `loading` function:

```
var var_1;
setTimeout(function(){ 
    var_1 = 1; 
}, 2500);
```

Here, the timeout is set immediately after var_1 is made. So you don't need to do any extra function calling.
Your translation has a good way, but it could be made easier like this.